# for-loop in C explained

Tags: c, loops

I see a for loop in C like this:

`for (i=myid; i < NUM_STEPS; i += nprocs)`

Let's say 
`myid = 1;`
`NUM_STEPS = 5;`
`nprocs = 3;`.
Now I start the for loop, I wonder if the intepretation is correct:

1st iteration: `i = 1 + 1 = 2`

2nd iteration: `i = 2 + 1 = 3`

Now since `i` hits the value of `nprocs`, the for loop ends.

Comment: No, first iteration `i = 1`. It says so in the initialization clause of the loop.

Comment: No, you've got it wrong. It increments by the value of `nprocs` and stops when it's greater than or equal to `NUM_STEPS`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ so 1st iteration is 1 + 3 = 4, then stops?

Comment: @kyle The condition is checked at the start of each iteration. 1st iteration: 1 < 5; 2nd iteration: 4 < 5; 3rd iteration: 7 < 5 is False, so stop.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ok thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First iteration:

```
i = 1
```

Second iteration:

```
i = 1 + 3 = 4
```

Then:

```
i = 4 + 3 = 7
```

which is greater than 5, thus the loop will not be executed.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i=myid; i < NUM_STEPS; i += nprocs) {
    // ...
}
```

means

```
i = myid;
while(i < NUM_STEPS) {
    // ...
    i += nprocs;
}
```

In your case you have two iterations: `i = 1` and `i = 4`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i=myid; i < NUM_STEPS; i += nprocs)
```

Here, first iteration `i` is `1` and check the condition

```
= i <  NUM_STEPS 
= 1 < 5
= true
```

then executed for loop body. After completed first iteration then control goes to for loop increment statement.

```
= i+=nprocs
= i = i + nprocs
= i = 1 + 3
= i = 4
```

Now i become 4 in second iteration and condition become `true`.

```
= i <  NUM_STEPS 
= 4 < 5
= true
```

Then executed for loop body. After completed first iteration then control goes to for loop increment statement.

```
= i+=nprocs
= i = i + nprocs
= i = 4 + 3
= i = 7
```

Now i become `7` in second iteration and condition become `false`.

```
= i <  NUM_STEPS 
= 7 < 5
= false
```